# Fitting Page and Contents to a Window and Form c#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a window that has a a frame in which I add pages two. So far I have Page1 and Page2. By using the NavigationService I can move between the two pages within the same window, something I have spent some time trying to implement.

The issue now however is that whilst the Window is maximised (which I want) the page's content is only displayed in the top-left hand corner of the Window.

I understand this is purely a matter of choosing the correct containers however I am a bit stuck in what I should go for, this is the layout of each section;

```
Window - Contains a form
Pages (added to the form) - Contain a dock panel - Contains a canvas - Contains elements (buttons etc)
```

As I say the issue is that the page is only displayed in the top-left hand corner, I would like the page to "grow" with the Window.

Code for the Window:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="WPFNavigation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFNavigation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test1" Height="500" Width="500" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Frame x:Name="frame" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Window>
```

Code for a Page:

```
<Page x:Class="WPFNavigation.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFNavigation"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Page1" WindowTitle="Page 1">
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" LastChildFill="False" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280">
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="280">
            <Button x:Name="button_Page1" Content="Page 1" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="235" Width="75"/>
            <Button x:Name="button_Page2" Content="Page 2" Canvas.Left="99" Canvas.Top="235" Width="75" Click="button_Copy_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="button_Page3" Content="Page 3" Canvas.Left="179" Canvas.Top="235" Width="75"/>
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are using **absolute positioning** to position your elements on a `Canvas` and you are also **explicitly** setting the `Width` of elements. This doesn't play well with dynamic window sizes.

By setting the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` you are making the assumption that every device that this application runs on can render the view in exactly the same way. Imagine what your application would look like on a **phone**, or a screen with a **lower resolution**.

Instead, consider using a `Grid`, or make better use of your `DockPanel`, here's an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>            
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Hello"/>        
    <Button Content="World" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="Le toucan has arrived" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

This is obviously a very simple example however it showcases relative sizes and positioning of elements instead of explicitly setting the `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top` and setting the `Width`.

The above example plays well with dynamic window sizing, if you were to resize the window, then the `TextBox` will resize as the column it sits inside is set to a `*` width, which basically means *"fill all available space"*.

If you're in a scenario where you want the content of a page to **scale** up so that it fills all available space, then you can use a `ViewBox`, you can find a tutorial [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFViewbox.aspx). These are tricky to get right, however I would recommend that you get to grips with other layout panels before implementing a `ViewBox`, they should be used with care as it's very easy to screw up the user experience where content can become either too small or too large.

Explicitly setting the `Width` and/or `Height` of an element should be an absolute last resort. Allowing your application to transition nicely when the application is resized is what makes any user experience more *delightful*, and the way of which to achieve that is to use **relative** sizes and positions.

I would recommend reading up on this topic [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFGrid.aspx) and [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFDockPanel.aspx).

Comment: Even after modifying the Page to use a Grid, it is still only snapped into the very top left when the window is maximised (i.e. the page in the designer is much smaller than the window maximised, and it does not "grow" with it)

Comment: I think what you're after is a `ViewBox`. Try wrapping the page content inside a `ViewBox` element.

Comment: What I'm trying to explain here Mike is that regardless of what container I use, the Page itself is still not growing with the size of the Window. The contents are now moving round and growing with the page, but without the Page growing with the Window it's still not what I want.

Comment: Your `DockPanel` has a fixed `Width` and `Height`, try removing these.